# rsync ignores dry-run

Tags: rsync

I have just run the following command in a `bash` script

```
rsync -av -update  --dry-run --delete $EX "$FROM" "$TO"
```

the sync ran, `--dry-run` was ignored  (luckily that was ok this time).

Does any one see any reason why `--dry-run` would be ignored here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because the correct option is `--update`, not `-update`. Your command should be:

```
rsync -av --update --dry-run ...
```

When `rsync` does the dry-running, the last line of default `rsync` stat output will show the string `(DRY RUN)` e.g.:

```
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00 (DRY RUN)
```

Full output:

```
% rsync -av --update --dry-run foobar out/
sending incremental file list
foobar

sent 62 bytes  received 19 bytes  162.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00 (DRY RUN)
```

Comment: thank you that solved it, dangerous mistake to make on my part.

Comment: @nogad It happens. Whenever in doubt, take a peek at the man page :)

Comment: i dont understand why some arguments require one hash and some two

Comment: @nogad For expanded option name, most of them use `--` (POSIX), `-` is typically used for single letter (short) arguments. If you find a long argument using `-`, thats an exception.

Comment: @nogad You were really unlucky as the `-e` part of the `[-]-update` needs a value so it gobbled up the next argument i.e. `--dry-run`.  If your to and from directories were local then the `-e` option would not be used, and wouldn't cause a fail.